# Did this building cause carpet to burn and cars to melt?

Tags: physics, united-kingdom, architecture

The [BBC reports](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-23948811) that a building with curved glass in London appears to have caused damage nearby as a result of the architecture focusing the sun's rays.

[image]

Seems plausible enough to me, but is this true?

An aside: this made me think of Charles Dryfus' threat to destroy the world in *[The Pink Panther Strikes Again](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075066/?ref_=tt_rec_tt)* (because the doomsday weapon was powered by the sun, IIRC):

[image]

Comment: Here's another article with some background knowledge about it, and a very damning picture of the hot spot - http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-23944679

Comment: Wow: "One reading suggests hot spot was 91.3C today"

Comment: You can see that it's at least beginning to focus, in the photograph: the reflection of the sun is spread across the building.

Comment: It doesn't take a big mirror to melt metal ([example Youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tt7RG3UR4c)). Maybe it's fortunate that the glass isn't more reflective, and building better focused.

Comment: I'd be interested to see some calculations about how much the building is likely to concentrate the relative solar power of the sun’s radiation. That is, how much more in watts/sq m is normal british solar insolation increased by the “mirror” of the building design and how significant is this compared to solar radiative flux in other places.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, the story has been confirmed by many reliable sources and the developers have taken responsibility.

[This story from the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-23944679) explains how:

> It's like starting a fire with a parabolic mirror.

[image: Parabolic mirror]

The location of the focal point, F, depends on the curvature of the parabola. A shallow curve, like that of the building, places the focal point further away from the mirror.

[The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/sep/03/walkie-talkie-skyscraper) mentions that same architect's work [has done this before](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/39403349/ns/travel-news/t/death-ray-vegas-hotel-pool-heats-guests/#.UidQXGTTVc0), in Las Vegas:

> it has happened before – in a project by the very same architect... they realised this special glass was in fact burning their guests as they lounged by the swimming pool beneath the soaring mirrored facades

[CNN confirms](http://www.cnn.com/2013/09/03/world/europe/uk-london-building-melts-car/) the burning happened:

> A skyscraper whose reflected rays have the power to melt cars...

And, the [developers have taken responsibility](http://www.cnn.com/2013/09/03/world/europe/uk-london-building-melts-car/):

> Canary Wharf Construction and Land Securities have been very good and agreed to pay for the damage, and accept that there is an issue which they will resolve.

Comment: They ought to put some concentration-suitable PV panels on that parking spot.  Should be able to get at least a few kilowatts out of it.

Comment: @Compro - the focal point moves with the sun, both through the day and through the seasons.

Comment: I'm appalled that this isn't the first time this architect did it.  Not realizing it was an issue the first time is understandable; but to do it again after it caused a big fuss the first time is IMO negligent.

Comment: @DanNeely probably just for publicitiy..

Comment: I am just glad it was called a parabolic mirror and not a magnifying glass as some sources have called it...

Comment: @DanNeely - Or it could be they made changes which they thought would prevent it, but didn't.  Which is incompetent, but not necessarily negligent.